# Getting the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'url' discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am trying to make a discord bot which sends welcome messages with customized images to the users that enter to the server. I tried to search it in internet but I couldn't find any answers. If you know a way to fix this please write.

This is the error i get:

```
Message='str' object has no attribute 'url'
  Source="(filepath)"
  StackTrace:
  File "(filepath)", line 32, in on_member_join (Current frame)
    profile_image = await load_image_async(str(member.avatar.url))
  File "(filepath)", line 93, in <module>
    bot.run('(bot_token)')
```

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from easy_pil import Editor, load_image_async, Font



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in problemless as {0.user}'.format(bot))


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = member.guild.system_channel
    background = Editor("background.jpg")
    profile_image = await load_image_async(str(member.avatar.url))

    profile = Editor(profile_image).resize((150,150)).circle_image()
    poppins = Font.poppins(size=50, variant="bold")

    poppins_small = Font.poppins(size=20, variant ="light")
    
    background.paste(profile, (325,90))
    background.ellipse((325, 90), 150, 150, outline="white",stroke_width=5)

    background.text((400, 260), f"Welcome {member.guild.name}", color="white", font=poppins, align="center")
    background.text((400,325), f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", color="white", font=poppins_small,align="center")

    file = discord.File(fp=background.image_bytes, filename="background.jpg")
    await channel.send(f"Hello {member.mention}! Welcome To **{member.guild.name}**")
    await channel.send(file=file)
bot.run('(token)')
```

Comment: Which version of `discord.py` are you using? `pip freeze | grep discord` (`pip freeze | findstr discord` on Windows)

Comment: I am using the version 1.7.3

Comment: I'd suggest to use `avatar_url` instead of `avatar.url`. It seems library developers changed API a bit between 1.7 and 2.0, and current documentation majorly refers 2.0 version. Example usage is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637647/how-to-increase-the-waiting-time-for-a-response-from-a-discord-bot

Comment: Acording to [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.Member.avatar), `User.avatar` should be of type `Asset` and not `str`. This is a weird behaviour. Can you try to `print(type(member.avatar))` and `print(type(member))` to further isolate the problem?  Edit: Appears to be a problem with a change of the API as @Alex mentioned.

Comment: So what was the solution?)

Comment: changing it to avatar_url

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the portion of `member.avatar.url` in your code, other than missing a conditional for *`if the user does not have an avatar, do:`*, which is what the error is reporting.

You can solve that by including an if conditional like below:

```
default_avatar = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/1.png'

profile_image = await load_image_async(member.avatar.url) if member.avatar else await load_image_async(default_avatar)
```

or

```
default_avatar = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/1.png'

if member.avatar:
    profile_image = await load_image_async(member.avatar.url)
else:
    profile_image = await load_image_async(default_avatar)
```

As for the image editing portion of the code, I'm unable to validate.